# How to improve shrinking process for 1.5TB in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with 1.5TB size. We are cleanup prod data daily and reclaimed 600gb space. We are performing shrink operations but it will take roughly 7hrs to complete.This server meant for only shrink ,no other operation running on it. How to bring down shrink process time to 4or 5hrs. Initial memory is 64GB but after increasing the memory to 128GB the process time not reduced. Tell us how to improve the shrink process l.

Answer (score 3):

### chunkin'

You can shrink things [in chunks](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/e2d33152deb97a2e2f45) to avoid the pain of a single big shrink.

It may still take a very long time, depending on many local factors, but you can make progress over multiple runs to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 1):

> How to improve shrinking process for 1.5TB in SQL server.

You don't...or you [don't do it](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/). Shrinking is a resource wasteful, mostly unnecessary, heavy operation, that results in the [side effects of fragmentation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) too.

> We are cleanup prod data daily and reclaimed 600gb space. We are performing shrink operations but it will take roughly 7hrs to complete

I really hope you're not trying to shrink daily then. It's pointless. You have daily growth that obviously needs the space from disk. **When you delete old data, it frees up the space internally already so that new data can override it without using more disk space.** All shrinking does is release that freed up space back to the disk to sit idle until the database grows again.

Shrinking would be wasteful for it to only grow right again in the next day or so. Shrink and growth operations are resource intensive. The only potential use case for shrinking is as a *one-time* cleanup after a massive change in your data retention **process**. For example, if a table that stored 10 years worth of data was changed to now only store 2 years worth moving forward, and it wasn't going to ever grow near its previous size again. Then, if the space freed up from the deletion wasn't ever going to be used elsewhere in the database, it *may* make sense to shrink.

> This server meant for only shrink ,no other operation running on it.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to say here, because a server that's only meant to be used for shrinking would be a pointless server.

> How to bring down shrink process time to 4or 5hrs. Initial memory is 64GB but after increasing the memory to 128GB the process time not reduced.

Shrinking is *mostly* a disk intensive operation, so there's not much you can do currently. You can upgrade your disk to a faster one eventually, but that will require you to transfer the database over to it anyway. Or, as I initially stated, you just don't shrink.